# Regex reject string if it contains only certain characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am trying to achieve the following using regex in C# in .Net application

I need to restrict strings which contains 'ONLY' these three special characters namely #,@ and %. Any other character is allowed

some examples

ab#c - allowed

abc#@ - allowed

#%abc - allowed

#@% - not allowed

##@ - not allowed

What I tried
`^(?!(#|@|%)+$)`
But it doesn't seem to work as expected. Where am I going wrong ?

I am using data annotations on the property, so I am looking for a regex pattern that can exclude the incorrect input strings. I cannot use the `Regex.IsMatch()` function.

Clarification: My string should accept any characters. The only case it should fail is when the input string only has #,@ or %.

Comment: does this `^[#@%]+$` work for you?

Comment: `[^#@%]+` - at least one symbol other then `#, @, %`?

Comment: If you consider `$` and word chars as "valid" , you need `^[#@%$]*[\w$][\w$#@%]*$`. Please explain your requirements.

Comment: So the case is my string can accept any character. The only restriction I want in place is to restrict strings that have only #, @ or %.

Comment: Then `^[^#@%]*$` or `^[^#@%]+$`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't elegant but does the job I think: `^[\w#@%]*\w+[\w#@%]*$`

[image: screen shot]

[Works for your examples](https://regex101.com/r/PzfTsw/1)

I'm taking "non-special" characters to mean `\w`.

Comment: `^[#@%]*\w[\w#@%]*$` is more optimal. Note it includes `_`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew In case of %$$ it fails. % is an invalid, but $ is acceptable. If the string contains at least one valid character, it should be acceptable.

Comment: @wickjon Then this answer is wrong.